# How to add and merge values of the same map in java

Tags: java, spring

Hi I am having trouble in adding the integer value of my map and merging the string value of it what I want to do is for example I have the following code:

```
List<Object[]> results = customerRepository.findByAddress();

for(Object[] object : results) {
    Map<Object, Object> location = new LinkedHashMap<>();
    location.put("Region", object[0]);
    location.put("Tally", object[1]);
    for(String obj : regionOne) {
        if(object[0].equals(obj)) {
            location.replace("Region", "Region I");
        }
    }
}
```

and this is the following data:

```
Region: Pasig
Tally: 2
Region: Taguig
Tally: 2
```

what I want is to add the value of Tally so 2 + 2 = 4
and merge and replace Pasig and Taguig to Region I

so the results should be

```
 Region: Region I
 Tally: 4
```

I have looked at the merge function and it seems that it is not what I'm looking for or I just didn't quite get it Thanks in advance.

Comment: What is `regionOne` ?

Comment: And why are you using `Objects` ?

Comment: @Scary Wombat regionOne is an array

Comment: Looks like you need to use a Strings, not Objects

Comment: Okay but do you know how would I add tally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using Java 8 or bigger, Map::computeIfPresent could be useful for your question.

And by the way, I think it is better to separate the business part from your code when asking questions.

Comment: Oh thanks for the advice I am actually looking at the compute method right now and will get back to this after I test it out

Comment: I did it like this     location.compute("Tally", (k, oldVal) -> (oldVal == null ? 0: oldVal + "+" + object[1])); will this work as intended?

Comment: location.compute("Tally", (k, oldVal) -> (oldVal == null ? 0: oldVal + Integer.valueof(object[1])));
you may want this.

Comment: Thanks it worked I wrote it like this             location.compute("Tally", (k, oldVal) -> (oldVal == null ? 0: 
             ((BigInteger) oldVal).add((BigInteger) object[1])));